# Is there a way to determine from bash what is wrong with fish?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, fish

Just installed oh-my-fish and start modifying oh-my-fish default theme under another name and broke something.

Now after login the cursor just blinks and I can write but nothing is interpreted as command.

What I change can be seen in my [dotfiles](https://github.com/nexusstar/dotfiles/tree/omf-add-working)

Switched to another tty and log as root change shell to bash and everything works so I am sure the problem is something in my fish configuration but didn't know how to determine what it could be.

So is there a way to determine from bash what is wrong with fish?

Comment: You can just start fish from bash and kill it again if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Wieland will try that but sill not sure how to determine what cause the problem